# compiling my code to use mongodb c driver in OSX via xcode

Tags: c++, c, xcode, macos, mongodb

I am trying to make a C application on OSX(10.9.5) which will connect to mongodb and perform CRUD operations. I am using the release 1.3.5 which I downloaded from: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/releases/tag/1.3.5
I was sucessfully able to install mongo on my system. I am making my application which will use the library to perform CRUD operations. I am using Xcode 6.1.1 as my IDEon osx. I have given the appropriate path for header files in the ide and have no warnings or error before the run. I have given search path for dynamic libraries as well so I think linking should be happening fine as well. However when I try to run I get the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "_bson_as_json", referenced from:
>
> ```
>   _main in find.o   "_bson_destroy", referenced from:
>   _main in find.o   "_bson_free", referenced from:
>   _main in find.o   "_bson_new", referenced from:
>   _main in find.o   "_mongoc_cleanup", referenced from:
>   _main in find.o   "_mongoc_client_destroy", referenced from:
>   _main in find.o   "_mongoc_client_get_collection", referenced from:
>   _main in find.o   "_mongoc_client_new", referenced from:
>   _main in find.o   "_mongoc_collection_destroy", referenced from:
>   _main in find.o   "_mongoc_collection_find", referenced from:
>   _main in find.o   "_mongoc_cursor_destroy", referenced from:
>   _main in find.o   "_mongoc_cursor_next", referenced from:
>   _main in find.o   "_mongoc_init", referenced from:
>   _main in find.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang:error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've specified the dynamic library path for libmongoc-1.0.so but not the library it depends on, libbson-1.0.so. Both libraries were installed when you built the driver, so you should be able to specify an additional path and your program will link correctly.